# El proveedor OLE DB "SQLNCLI11" del servidor vinculado no pudo iniciar una transacción distribuida

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, servidor, transacciones

tengo un procedimiento almacenado en un servidor vinculado que devuelve un conjundo de registros , hago una llamada a ese procedimiento "remoto" desde un procedimiento almacenado en otro servidor (local) sin problemas. El inconveniente aparece cuando intento procesar esos datos en el procedimiento local, ya sea intentando pasarlo a una variable de tipo table, a una tabla temporal , o a un cursor.
El error completo  es :

> El proveedor OLE DB "SQLNCLI11" del servidor vinculado "SERVERVINCULADO"
> devolvió el mensaje "No transaction is active.". Mens 7391, Nivel 16,
> Estado 2, Procedimiento sp_trabajosdelDia ,
> Línea 38 No se pudo realizar la operación porque el proveedor OLE DB
> "SQLNCLI11" del servidor vinculado "SERVERVINCULADO" no pudo iniciar una
> transacción distribuida.

El procedimiento que funciona es:

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE sp_trabajosdelDia @centro TINYINT, @servicio SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC   SERVERVINCULADO.integracion.dbo.sp_trabajos  @centro, @servicio;

END
```

Luego si agrego alguna otra linea - intenté varias alternativas- me devuelve el mensaje anterior. Ejemplo:

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE sp_trabajosdelDia @centro TINYINT, @servicio SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT);
    INSERT @table (id)
    EXEC   SERVERVINCULADO.integracion.dbo.sp_trabajos  @centro, @servicio;

END
```

No entiendo xq intenta el servidor vinculado no responde a la solicitud, si lo que agrego se ejecuta en mi servidor local.
Alguien podría ayudarme? Hace tiempo estoy lidiando con esto y no logro resolverlo. Miré toda la configuración que encontré investigando, pero si alguien me da pautas de donde podría estar la falla, volvería a revisar nuevamente.
Gracias!

Comment: Cuando abres el procedimiento se inicia una transacción de modo implicita. Como no se ve el código y esto es todo imaginar, porque no hay `linea 38`, en lo expuesto. Yo haría una transacción explicita. Luego puedes hacer un savePoint/commit una vez recuperados los datos....haber si soluciona el problema. Y a partir de eso avanzas. O no.

Comment: No inclui el codigo xq es un select unicamente

Comment: Lo solucioné con un parámetro de salida en el procedimiento remoto.